# Running NodeJS Code from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, request

So I have just been getting into learning NodeJS as part of learning how to build a webscraping tool for a project I wanted to make.

I have all the content I need from the NodeJS file when I run the file directly through the terminal, but I wanted to know how to run the code directly from a website I am building to display the content I get from webscraping.

Any and all help is appreciated!
(Also I am new to stackoverflow, so if you need any more info then I would be glad to help!)

Answer (score 2):

Since Node.js runs on server side, you need to call the Node.js server through ajax and get the response back.

This website shows how to do [Web Scraping in Node.js](http://www.codingdefined.com/2016/01/web-scraping-in-nodejs.html), now when you get the data pass it as a response to the browser.

You may also check [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) which gives you "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework for Node.js".

Answer (score 2):

So you have working node application written in javascript. Perfect.

Now you want to run that in browser mode. you can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) for the same. Browserify will package all the nodejs module in a bundle and let you require from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but you should look into a cloud9 space (its free) and using express to render the HTML.  It's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nodejs tutorial in tutorialspoint [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/] is powerful solution. It is just advice.